# Generate complex (non-convex) polyhedron UV mapping

Tags: c#, 3d, uv-mapping, wpf, computational-geometry

I need to find an approach to the problem of generating texture maps for non-convex polyhedrons without using a design tool like Maya. Specifically, I am mapping simulation results data onto a 3D surface, and I need to write code which generates the maps. My target platform is WPF, but I'm aware that this computation problem is wider than that.

One generic approach (in WPF) uses a gradient color brush as an overall texture to just map colors, but if the facets in the polyhedron are very narrow or the mapped (u,v) coordinates are very far apart on the same facet, the image gets noisy. Another approach employs Phong or Gouraud Shading, but those features are missing in some 3D libraries which favor texturing over specifying colors at each vertex. So, I'm looking for a way to get a good texture map generated.

What (specific) articles or books would contain descriptions of such an algorithm? If it helps in identifying a correct algorithm, all of the surfaces entirely enclose a 3-D space, there is no facet normal data, and I'll be able to identify a "parting line" which segregates one part of the surface from the other, as one might in order to create a mold for the shape.

Comment: As it stands right now, this questions feels like a "getting started" question and shows little sign of resea... googling.

Comment: There are automated tools for this, in a library form that you can incorporate into your program. [UVAtlas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206321.aspx) is an example, though it might not be the best choice since I don't think it has native C# bindings.

Comment: Native C# bindings are less important. I can always package things into an executable and use file-based IPC. Clunky, but possible.